# How listen new messages in vk skd?

Tags: android, android-service, real-time, vk-sdk

I am using vk sdk for my android app. The app can send and receive messages to another users. In order to get the list of messages I used `/method/messages.getHistory` but how to listen new messages event when another user send me a message? For example in firebase - since it is realtime db we can do it. But how get to know when new message was sent using vk sdk like in realtime? I have an idea to start Service which will check new messages every 5 sec, but I think it is bad solution since it will drain battery etc.